# How can I check if there is an assignment in a macro's parameter?

Tags: c++, c, string, enums, macros

How can we check if there is an assignment in a macro param as in below example?

define:

```
#define value(x) {...}
```

call:

```
case a: value( a = 10 )
case b: value( 10 )
```

what i want to do is implement a string enum in below way:

```
#define STR_ENUM_DICT_ITEM_(value)  [@((MethodX value)) stringValue]:@#value,
#define STR_ENUM_DICT_ITEM(idx, value)  STR_ENUM_DICT_ITEM_(value)         

#define STR_ENUM(type, name, ...) \
typedef NS_ENUM (type, name){__VA_ARGS__}; \
NSString *name##_S(type value) \
{ \
    static NSDictionary   *values; \
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken; \
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ \
        values = @{ \
            metamacro_foreach(STR_ENUM_DICT_ITEM, , __VA_ARGS__) \
        }; \
    }); \
    return [values valueForKey:[@(value)stringValue]]; \
}  

STR_ENUM(NSUInteger, MethodX,
   Method1 = 100// this is comment
   , Method2
   , Method3 = Method1
);
```

so i need to check if there is a assignment in the param, or other way 
can get the value of (Method1 = 100) or (Method3 = Method1), which result is 100, 100.

Comment: Since the preprocessor only does simple text replacement, you can't do much about checking expanded parameters.

Comment: To nitpick:  Marcos aren't called.

Comment: Presumably you mean a check at compile time, not run time?

Comment: Why the `enums` tag, btw?

Comment: Why do people prefer macros? The compiler is better as it has more information

Comment: Do you prefer to check for assignment, or make the assignment get ignored?

Comment: i just want to get correct value in blow cases
    
    /// macro define
    #define value(x)    .....

    /// case
    value( Method1 = 100 )          /// result 100 
    value( Method2 )                /// result 101
    value( Method3 = Method1)       /// result 100
    value( Method4 = Method3 + 100)  /// result 200

Comment: So, is this objective c++, or just objective c? There is a solution in c++, but none in c that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Not very efficient in terms of performance but it works:

```
#define value(x) \
  do { \
    assert(!strchr(#x, '=')); \
    /* rest of macro */ \
  } while (0)
```

This is a simple example only covering the two cases provided by the OP. However, using the `#` operator to convert the macro's argument into a "string" one can create as complex rules to test against as one likes.

Comment: Depends on what behaviour the author wants for `value(a==10)` or even on `value('=')`.

Comment: BTW, I think you can convert it into a compile-time check, as `#x` is known at compile time, so no problems with perfomance

Comment: @Wangchao, I've asked in two of your questions - what language is this? There is a compile-time solution in C++. Is this Objective-C++ or Objective-C? You've tagged the question with both c and c++ tags but few people actually use Objective-C++.

Comment: Sorry, I just see the message. This is just a c/c++ problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can you specify in more details which cases do you want to distinguish? How about

```
value(a)
value(a+2)
value(a==10)
value(a<=10)
value('=')
```

?

What do you want to happen in case it contains assignment? Compilation error or something other?

For a compilation error, I managed to get the following work

```
#define check(a) if (a==a);

int main() {
   int a;
   check(10);
   check(a);
   check(a+2);
   check(a==10);
   check(a<=10);
   check('=');
   check(a=10);
   return 0;
}
```

Every macros except the `a=10` compiles. The latter turns into `a=10==a=10`, which does not compile.